# Ruby on Rails installing, bin is not a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debian

When I do:

```
    sudo gem install rails
```

I get:

```
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOTDIR)
    Not a directory - /usr/local/bin/rackup
```

Also get an error if I try to cd into /usr/local/bin
Can anyone give a hint on what is going on?

Comment: What is the output of the following command? `file /usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

On Debian you need to be in the staff group to write to that directory (if it exists).

Try

```
$ sudo usermod -aG staff <username>
```

if it doesn't exist

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/rackup
ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/rackup: No such file or directory
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/bin/rackup
```